# How can I get the path to my Resources folder in Xcode without giving an absolute path?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have this snippet of code:

```
NSPasteboard *pboard = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName:NSDragPboard];
[pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLPboardType] owner:nil];
[pboard writeObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/dw/Desktop/macapp/Menulet/logo.png"]]];
```

And I don't want to use an absolute path but when I try using just "logo.png" it gives the following error:

```
NSURLs written to the pasteboard via NSPasteboardWriting must be absolute URLs.  NSURL 'logo.png -- file://localhost/Users/dw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Menulet-bvwpfkjlcufhxubvaxubgnubtfgi/Build/Products/Debug/' is not an absolute URL.
```

Is there anyway to not have to hardcode it? logo.png is currently in my Resources folder in Xcode.

**EDIT:**
How can I get a directory path instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should make the trick:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"logo" ofType:@"png"]
```

Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thanks! How can I make this work with a directory instead? what would the type be? "dir"?

Comment: Check documentation, everything is explained there. There is an appropriate method.

Comment: I tried
    `[pboard writeObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],"test", nil]]]];` but it didn't work